# $T \colon \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $T\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\1 \end{bmatrix}=3$ and $T\begin{bmatrix} -1 \\2 \end{bmatrix}=6$

Tags: linear-algebra

Seeking some help with the following midterm review question:

Give a linear transformation $T \colon \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $T\begin{bmatrix}
1  
\\1
\end{bmatrix}=3$ and $T\begin{bmatrix}
-1  
\\2
\end{bmatrix}=6$ and find a matrix $A$ such that $T=T_A$. So $T$ is left multiplication by $A$.

Comment: I think the only was this can work is to pick a 1 by 2 matrix $[a ..b]$. If you perform the multiplications, you get a system of two linear equations with 2 unknowns from which $a$ and $b$ can be found. Otherwise I wouldn't know...

Comment: @ levap thank you for your edit. Any idea how to proceed with thus problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can substitute $A = \begin{bmatrix} a & b\end{bmatrix}$ and solve the resulting system of equations. Alternatively:

$$A \begin{bmatrix} 1&-1\\1&2\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}3&6\end{bmatrix}$$

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}3&6\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1&-1\\1&2\end{bmatrix}^{-1}$$

Comment: is this the complete answer?

Comment: No, but it should help you figure out the answer.

Comment: okay I will try to proceed fromhere

Comment: @ Michael Biro  so all I would need to do is solve the system of equations?

Comment: Yes, that should work.